# AWS IAM and RBAC for application specific permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, rbac

I need to implement RBAC in my application. Right now, I'm trying to understand is AWS IAM Group a right way to go. Theoretically, I may create an IAM Group, assign users to this group. Also, I may create IAM Role with permissions and assign to the same group. As far as I understand  - with IAM Role I may define permissions for AWS resources like S3, RDS, Redshift and so on.

This is a physical AWS resources in my AWS account. But how about logical or, in other words - application specific permissions for not real AWS resources? Like for example - useMayInviteOtherUsers, userCanPlayThePiano and so on. Is it possible to define such permissions with AWS IAM? And if so, is it a right way to go? Or such RBAC model should be internally implemented inside my application without AWS IAM?

Comment: No, that is not possible through IAM. You need to implement that stuff yourself.

Comment: Incidental to the question, but you have muddled *roles* with *policies*. In AWS IAM, a *policy* defines a set of permissions, which can then be associated with a user, a group, or a role. For example, an EC2 instance has an associated role, granting it whatever permissions are in the policies attached to that role.